# static files in django framework that holds css and javascript they cant display in the web browser

Tags: python, django

I already have an index file in a template folder that hold the html code,Also i have css and javascript file in the static folder so when i load the browser i only see the index content without css and javascript

in setting.py file i set clearly the path to the static files that hold css and javascript also in index file we put special tags that specify our static files

The following is the setting.py contents:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STARTICFILES_DIRS=[

     os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

The following is the index file contents:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Travello</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="

{%static'styles/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

I expect the output of css style and javascipt functionality

Comment: Run `manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

STARTICFILES_DIRS is a typo. It is supposed to be STATICFILES_DIR.

STATICFILES_DIRS is the list of folders where Django will search for additional static files aside from the static folder of each app installed.

`python manage.py collectstatic` collects all the files defined inside static/ folder in your applications and puts it all to the static root.